# How do you import XML data into Excel using Office Add-ins (formerly Apps for Office) programmatically using JavaScript

Tags: c#, vsto, office365, add-in, office-js

Is it possible to import XML data into Excel using Office Add-ins (formerly Apps for Office) programmatically using JavaScript

I do this in VSTO (c#) using this method:- 
        *ActiveWorkbook.XmlImport(Url, out xMap, true, Cell);*

but would like to do it using JavaScript in the new Office Add-ins.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which version of Office are you targeting? That's very important information as what's available differs quite a bit between 2013 and 2016...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no explicit "importFromXml" method. However, especially if you're using Office 2016, you could use an ajax call to get the XML, and then create a Range or Table object and populate its values based on the received XML.  Something like:

```js
$.ajax("url").done(function(data) {
    Excel.run(function(ctx) {
        var sheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getActiveSheet();
        var firstCell = sheet.getCell(0,0);
        var lastCell = sheet.getCell(data.values.length, data.values[0].length);
        firstCell.getBoundingRect(lastCell).values = data.values;
    }).catch(errorHandler);
}).fail(errorHandler);
```

~ Michael Zlatkovsky, developer on Office Extensibility team, MSFT